# How to Convert NumberString to Number, Inside mongoDB aggregation Query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here

------- Water Color Modal ------------------------------

```
waterColorModal = {
     dateField : { type : Date },
     tempArray : { type : JSON }
}
```

------- Start Find Query ------------------------------

var dataFineQuery = { _id : xxxxxxx }

```
waterColorModal.aggregate([
  { $match    : dataFineQuery },
  { $project  : { dateField : 1, tempArray : 1} },
  { $group    : 
      { _id : { "$year" : "$dateField" }, 
      total : { 
           $sum : parseFloat({ "$arrayElemAt": [ "$tempArray", 1 ]})
              } 
  } 
], function ( err, result ) { 

console.log('-------------------------')
console.log(result) 
console.log('-------------------------')
)
```

One Water Color Collection

```
{ _id: 585392c8206ff324f955a4f0,
  dateField : Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (+0530),
  tempArray: [ '2344', '23423', '23432', '32432', '2342' ]
}
```

What I want is, 
Calculate Total Value for Each year

tempArray[1] <-- Only consider for total count

Thank,
Any suggestion comment or answer

Answer (score 1):

You need [map-reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) to perform JavaScript methods. You can try
Code:

```
db.runCommand({
    mapReduce: "waterColorModal",
    map: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tempArray.length; i++) {
          emit(new Date(this.dateField.toString()).getFullYear(), parseFloat(this.tempArray[i]));
        }

    },reduce: function(yearKey, totalValue) {
        count = 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < totalValue.length; ++index) {
            count += totalValue[index];
        }
        return count;
    },
    out: {
        inline: 1
    }
})
```